# How to hide Woocommerce 'Select options' and 'Add to cart' buttons

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to remove the Woocommerce 'select options' and 'add to cart' buttons on the shop and category pages on Wordpress (but keep the add to cart button on product pages.)

I tried a solution I found online that involved adding code to the Additional CSS section of the customizer, but it didn't seem to work. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to remove the button by removing the action that adds it.

You can do that by adding the following code to your child theme's `functions.php`

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
```

This will hide the button from all the places that involve a product list including but not limited to:

- shop page
- upsells/cross-sells
- archive pages including the search results page

Comment: This didn't do anything when I put it in the code.